# knowledgebase Library ratings

Tags: wiki, rating, content-rating

I have a Knowledgebase Library. I am (farm admin) able to rate documents . End users with contribute rights to the library rate the document but they never get updated.

Any idea? Timer job runs because if i log in as farm account my ratings are captured and saved in 10 minutes as timer job for this ones run every 10 minutes.

Comment: I followed this and everything setup properly. http://codename-srini.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-use-rating-control-in-sharepoint.html. Look at the September 2010 comment. I have exact same scenario. Ratings by system account are saved where user's rating are not.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me.

[Rating's not being saved](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51649/ratings-not-being-saved/51650#51650)

Go to User Profile Service Application in Central Administration. Click Manage User Permissions and check if all authenticated users has rights to Social Features.